# Php retrieve a set of values from an unique SQL row and display it in an HTML option list

Tags: php, sql, select

I am trying to display an SQL row which has a set of values in an HTML Select input.

Here is my table (row color is a varchar type) :

---

|**id**| |colors|

---

|**12**|  Red, Green, Blue
|**13**|  Yellow, Green
|**14**|  Yellow

---

It should implode the set of values in as many  as needed!

```
<select>
<option>Red</option>
<option>Green</option>
<option>Blue</option>
</select>
```

How can I do, please, something like this :

"for a selected row id"
"fetch all the color values and display each of them in an value"

```
echo '<select>';
$results = mysql_query("SELECT colors FROM MyTable where id='$id'");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
echo '<option>'.implode($rows['colors']).'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Thank you...

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble! One row/item is the db way!

Comment: Well, I have to do with what I have!

Comment: First I'd suggest you read about [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Secondly you should update your code to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). After that, learn about Prepared Statements to protect yourself against SQL injection. [MySQL is Deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the others have said is correct, you are not doing it the best way in the database. However, if you are required to use such a database, this code should help:

```
echo '<select>';
$results = mysql_query("SELECT colors FROM MyTable where id='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    $colors = explode(",", $row['colors']);
    $arr_length = count($colors);
    for ($i=0; $i<$arr_length; $i++){
        echo '<option>'.$colors[$i].'</option>';
    }

}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT colors FROM MyTable where id='$id'");
$option ='<select>';
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
 $new  = explode(",",$rows['colors']);
  foreach ($new as $value) {
   $option = $option . '<option>'. $value .'</option>';
  }
}
$option = $option . '</select>';
echo $option;
```